# "g++" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Tags: c++

instale MinGW para windows 10 para poder compilar c++ y me apareció el error del titulo, busque muchos tutoriales que decían de que debo arreglar las variables de entorno, y lo hice, pero el error persiste

el PATH es C:\MinGW\bin

Comment: Puedes seguir [estas instrucciones](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/mingweclipse/mingw.html) para la correcta instalación.

Comment: Si deseas añadir una ruta a las variables de entorno del sistema para compilar programas desde la consola de comandos del sistema, debes especificarla en la ruta llamada Path, sino no funcionara... Si no existe una ruta llamada Path, puedes crearla tu mismo. Si nombras a tu ruta con cualquier otro nombre que no sea path, el sistema no lo reconocera como un comando. ¡Buena suerte! espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinGW trae diferentes paquetes a instalar. Lo que te recomiendo hacer es ir manualmente a la carpeta de `C:\MinGW\bin` y buscar el archivo `g++.exe`. Si no encuentras el archivo lo más probable es que MinGW no instaló el compilador. Lo que podrías hacer en ese caso es volver a correr el instalador de MinGW.

En caso de que si encuentras el archivo `g++.exe` en esa respectiva carpeta tienes debes de revisar que el path esté correcto. Revisa que `C:\MinGW\bin` esté en la sección de variables del sistema, no en la del usuario local. Después de poner esta en el path reinicia tu computador por si acaso. Esto debería solucionar el problema.